Can I use the CC/CV converter as the LED strip driver?
I have a power supply - Molex from power supply unit (5V, max current - 11A). Besides lighting there are other consumers that do not need current stabilisation.  I want to power 9 ws2812b LED strips connected in parallel (each with 12 diodes). According to my calculations their maximum current consumption is 0.06A * 12 * 9 = ~6.5A. I don't aim to use the strip for wear and tear, so I want to limit the current to 5A to extend the life of the LEDs.  Would a cc/cv converter be suitable for this purpose?
Also two ssd drives are powered via the +5V line via a SATA Power connector. Will the pulse currents from the converter not interfere with their operation?
Can you suggest quality chips for current stabilisation up to 5A?

The WS2812B is an addressable LED, which means that it contains digital circuitry. If you limit the current to those LEDs, their supply voltage will drop and the digital circuitry within them will malfunction. This is because these LEDs control their own current draw (they contain constant-current sinks), which means that if they can't draw the current they want due to an external limiter, they'll pull down the external supply voltage until they fail to operate.
Since each of the LEDs already contains a programmable current sink, just program them to not light at full brightness if you want to extend their lifetime. They're individually controllable, after all.
To address the other question about interference: No, other loads connected to the same PSU won't interfere with the SSDs unless the PSU is overloaded.

Thanks for the answer. So the LED strip will draw a fixed current and will not burn out if the power of other consumers drops? Or is there a limit?

@phony51 The power supply will only ever supply as much current as all of the attached loads require. It can't just "push" more current through something. And yes, the LED strips regulate their own current. In fact, the brightness setting is the current setting. When you set the LEDs to be brighter, the little control chips in them increase the current that they push through the actual LED chips.

Correction: the way you push more current through something is by increasing the voltage. So you can, but not without changing the voltage. I think the brightness control works by PWM.

@QuittingDueToAntisemitism No, the LEDs contain active current regulation circuitry and will not draw more current even when the supply voltage increases.
